# How can I edit or create a new dictionary for spellcheck?

Tags: firefox, language-support, dictionary

I would like to take my American English dictionary and merge it with my Mexican Spanish dictionary, to create the language I actually use on a daily basis, which is Spanglish. This way I won't have to bother switching dictionaries when I switch languages mid-email, which I sometimes do.

How does Ubuntu store languages? Is it different from how Firefox does so, or do they share a file? How can I edit these files so that I can do my merge?

Muchas Gracias!